# How to delete .htaccess and .htpasswd and where are these files so I can delete them straight away?

Tags: .htaccess, search, find, box, .htpasswd

I have got XAMPP Version 1.8.3-4 and I am running this program in Mac. I want to delete this authentication mode but I can't find the .htaccess and .htpasswd files in my folder. Does anyone know where I can find it?

I found out that after deleting these files, there won't show the authentication message box to access localhost/phpmyadmin. There I want to delete these files to get rid of this authentication message box.

Answer (score 0):

The .htacess is stored in the htdocs folder under the root directory of the xampp install directory.

So most likely /.../Xampp/xamppfiles/htdoc/

Comment: will the name of the file would be .htaccess something? because I can't find any file named as such. @user3125923

Comment: You can not see in the finder a file that begins with a period (use console or FTP software)

Comment: This tutorial shows how to reveal hidden files such as .htaccess - http://www.turnwall.com/articles/show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x/